# Como puedo poner este div debajo de una imagen

Tags: css, bootstrap, div, img, position

Hola estoy intentando poner esta imagen por encima del div  class="background-img-1"

```html
section class="hero">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Columna izquierda -->
        <div class="col-6 p-5 justify-content-center">
          <h2>A Simple Bookmark Manager</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Consequuntur, asperiores suscipit quibusdam quo inventore quisquam
            fugiat. Ducimus nisi expedita ipsum vel est delectus, accusamus
            eaque, nesciunt, dicta fugiat earum amet.
          </p>
          <!-- buttons -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-5">
          <img
            src="/Recursos_projecte_sprint_2-20230213/Imagenes/illustration-hero.svg"
            alt=""
            class="z-3 position-absolute top-25"
          />
          <div
            class="background-img-1 z-n1 position-absolute end-0 top-50 w-25 p-3 h-50 d-inline-block"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero a mi me sale asi. muchas gracias

Comment: Incluye los links de bootstrap porfavor

Comment: Por favor, adjunta un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), necesitamos reproducir tu código para ver el problema con facilidad (HTML, CSS y la versión de Bootstrap que estás usando).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un contenedor que agregue la imagen y dentro un div absoluto que contenga la segunda imagen.

Otra idea seria usar un contenedor con una imagen dentro y la segunda imagen como background puesto a la derecha, ahora, como el objeto es muy simple la mejor forma sería crear el objeto con css y no agregar imagenes, con eso te ahorras un par de milisegundos en tiempos de carga, por ejemplo:

```css
.contenedor-imagen {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.contenedor-imagen img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.object {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 9999px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 9999px;
  background-color: hsl(231 69% 60% / 1 );
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-imagen">
  <img src="https://tailwindfromscratch.com/website-projects/bookmark/images/illustration-hero.svg">
<div class="object"></div>
</div>
```